# How do I highlight lines which does not have a duplicate string?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to find a regex to indicate lines which does **not** have a duplicate string.

Input:

```
 hi hello  hello hi
hello hi hello hi
 text hello  halo hi
hello  hello hi
 hello  halo hi
hello  hello hi
```

I want to highlight all lines which do contain the word `hello` but do NOT have another `hello` on the same line.

Expected Output:
Only line 3 and 5 must be highlighted.

I tried with this regex:

```
\(hello\)\(.*hello.*\)\@!
```

but it doesn't do what I want to do.

How can I highlight a pattern on a line (or the entire line) when there is no double pattern on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
^\(\(.*hello.*\)\{2,}\)\@!.*hello.*$
```

**explanation**

- \(.*hello.*\) : atom matching a sentence containing hello
- \(\(foo\)\{2,}\) : atom matching at least twice the atom \(foo\)
- \@! : unmatch if the last atom was matched
- .*hello.* : match a sentence with hello
- ^$ : to match the whole line

"Match a whole line not containing at least twice hello but containing hello"

Comment: would you mind explaining it ? (I'm reading docs but for now still not understanding how this work)

Comment: I think I got it: `((.*hello.*){2,})@!` means do not match two or hello in the sentence and the last `.*hello.*` tell it to match hello in the sentence, so the full match is for lines with hello once ... nice.

Comment: something like : matching a line `^$` not `\@!` containing at least twice hello `\(\(.*hello.*\){2,}\)` but containing hello `.*hello.*`

Comment: @odessos: Please add the explanation to your answer.  Answers are much easier to read when all of the information is in one place (as opposed to scattered through a bunch of comments).  It was for not including an explanation in the answer that I downvoted you.

Comment: No reason to downvote odessos. He toke the time to answer my question and did it well :) But it is true, an explanation is important. This regex is not easy to understand.

Comment: Does anyone know why `^\(\(.*hello.*\)\{2,}\)\@!.*\1.*$` gives a different matching as `^\(\(.*hello.*\)\{2,}\)\@!.*hello.*$`?